# How to jump back to the line of code that threw exception in Visual Studio 2010 debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, exception

Using the Visual Studio 2010 debugger, I am familiar with using the Call Stack window to see where the currently executing function was invoked from.

I'm working with some applications that have rather large `try` blocks.  Supposing that I pause execution of the code at a break point in the `catch` block, what is the simplest way to tell which line in the try block the exception was raised from?

I do know that the "Stack Trace" includes details such as the line number, but is there an easier way, such as a shortcut key, to navigate back to the line of code where the exception was raised?

**Update**: I would like to emphasize that I don't wish to move the execution point back to the `try` block; I simply want a simpler way of knowing which line the exception was raised from.

Answer (score 16):

If you goto "DEBUG", "Exceptions..." and then select "Thrown" against "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

[image: Exceptions]

Then when your code encounters an exception it will stop on the line with the error.

Comment: I didn't have the "Exceptions" option in VS 2017, so I had to enable it using the steps outlined here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.110).aspx. Or, just press ALT + CTRL + E

Comment: At last I will be able to inspect my variables during an exception! That's the tip of the year! thx

Answer (score 3):

A solution might be to make VS break on all exceptions:

Select `Exceptions` under the `Debug` menu, and check the "Thrown" box related to `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`.

Now VS should now stop and mark the line where the exception is thrown. You can **continue** as usual, by clicking the play button or F5.

The downside of this is that all exceptions will be caught in the same way, which may be annoying if you have a lot of them.

Comment: I'll see how this works out.  I just hate it when a large function throws an exception and I have to dig into the stack trace to see where it originated!

Comment: By the way, what about JavaScript errors?  Is there something similar I can use for JavaScript error handling?  A JavaScript `Error` object is treated similar to a .net `Exception` object.

Comment: I believe there is a setting/checkbox for JS in the same place, but I've never tested that. Should be easy to give it a try though!

Comment: The odd thing is, in the screenshot posted by @DaveShaw, there is a selection for that, but for some reason, it doesn't appear on my computer.  Maybe it's because of the version of Visual Studio I'm using (2010).

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2019:

Go to `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Exception Settings` and mark every exception under `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`.

[image]