# In Visual Studio exception handling, how do you target the exception away from the browser so you can view the call stack interactively?

Tags: visual-studio, exception, callstack

Until recently, when my VS 2013 code hit an exception, a grey dialog box would pop up, and the call stack window in VS would fill with the call stack. i would then be able to click on different lines in the stack, which would take me back to that point and let me view the variables.

This was good.

Sometime recently, some ninja broke into my secure home office, and changed a configuration setting of some sort, because now, when my code hits an exception, the information is all sent to a browser window. In some ways this is ok, because the entire call stack is visible in the browser window. But VS releases the information and there's nothing in the Call Stack window, and no way to interactively go back up the stack.

I've done a bunch of research but cannot for the life of me figure out what I did (I mean, what the ninja did) to change this, or how to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Answer turned out to be in a "Related" stack overflow: somehow I had unset the "Thrown" checkbox next to common-language-runtime in the Debug/Exceptions dialog box. See:

[How to jump back to the line of code that threw exception in Visual Studio 2010 debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010935/how-to-jump-back-to-the-line-of-code-that-threw-exception-in-visual-studio-2010?rq=1)